MySQL B-Tree Index on a Numeric Value in a VARCHAR Column - Inefficiency Concerns
im working with a MySQL database where I have a column of type VARCHAR, but it stores numeric values. I created a B-Tree index on this column to optimize queries like:
E.x > n
n < E.x
n = E.x

(where n is a positive float, and E ist the entity so that x represents the attribute)
However, I suspect the index does not provide the expected performance boost. My reasoning is as follows:
B-Tree indexes in MySQL rely on the natural ordering of the column's data. For VARCHAR, this ordering is lexicographical, not numerical.
Given that B-Tree indexes are designed to work efficiently based on a defined sort order, the mismatch between lexicographical sorting and numeric sorting likely leads to inefficiencies in index usage for numeric comparisons.
Additionally, the data in the query is cast to DECIMAL. I assume this also has an impact on performance.
Questions:
Is my assumption correct that this type of index is ineffective for numeric comparisons on a VARCHAR column?
Are there any workarounds or optimizations I could apply without changing the column's datatype (e.g., casting during queries)?
Would switching to a proper numeric datatype (like INT or DECIMAL) and indexing that be the only real solution?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

There's a quote attributed to software engineer and author Kent Beck:

"Make it work, make it right, make it fast."

The expectation is that you do these tasks in that order. I.e. worry about performance after you have made it right.
You haven't made it right yet. :-)
Suppose you evaluate this expression:
E.x > n

And the values are the following strings as VARCHARs:
'1024' > '256'

If you store these as strings, then '1024' is not greater lexically than '256'. The first character '1' is less than the first character '2'. So the expression returns false.
I doubt this is what you want for numeric comparisons.
Comparing numeric values when the numbers are stored as strings works only if the numbers always have the same number of digits:
'1024' > '0256'

'1024' > '2048'

So before you worry about the index efficiency when you store the numbers as strings, I would recommend you choose INT or DECIMAL data types just so the logic will evaluate correctly.
You will also find that indexes are efficient on INT or DECIMAL types.
